# How to create an iterative loop of multiple Python functions?

Tags: python, iterator, numerical-methods

I'm trying to write a Python code that is a numerical solver for 1-d heat conduction (using FVM) with a temperature dependent thermal conductivity.

The solver has three functions I need to iterate until convergence:

Conductivity function: takes an initial guess for temperature field and outputs nodal conductivities, dependent on past value of nodal temperatures.

Nodal coefficients: calculates nodal coefficients based on current nodal conductivities.

Nodal temperatures: uses a TDMA algorithm to calculate the nodal temperatures based on current coefficients.

Once the temperatures are calculated, the values are to be cycled through to the conductivity function to continue the loop until convergence.

I can make this work just fine when the conductivity is constant, but start getting issues when I try to implement this pseudocode. I get a maximum recursion depth exceeded error. My code is below:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import copy

# SOLUTION ALGORITHM

# Step 1: DATA  
def data(n, hw, he, TinfW, TinfE):    
    n = 5
    hw = 10**10
    he = 10**-10
    TinfW = 100
    TinfE = 10**12

    return n, hw, he, TinfW, TinfE    

# Step 2: GRID    
def grid(x1, x2, data):
    x1 = 0 
    x2 = 0.5
    xe = (x2-x1) / data(n, hw, he, TinfW, TinfE)[0]

    return xe

# Step 3: GAMSOR     
def gamsor(k, q, TDMA):
    k0 = 100
    beta = 20
    T0 = 25   
    for i in range(data(n, hw, he, TinfW, TinfE)[0]):
        k[i] = k0 + beta#*(TDMA(data, coeff)[i]-T0)
        q[i] = 10**5

    return k, q

 #Step 4: COEFF     
def coeff(Ae, Aw, Ap, data, gamsor, grid):
    for i in range(data(n, hw, he, TinfW, TinfE)[0]):       
        Ae[i] = Aw[i] = gamsor(k,q, TDMA(data, coeff))[0][i] /     grid(x1, x2, data)
        Ap[i] = Ae[i] + Aw[i]  

# Define "b" array - including source term and boundary conditions
        b = np.zeros((data(n, hw, he, TinfW, TinfE)[0], 1))
        b.fill(gamsor(k,q, TDMA(data, coeff))[1][i])    

        b[0] = (gamsor(k,q, TDMA(data, coeff))[1][i]*(grid(x1,x2,data)/2) + 
           data(n, hw, he, TinfW, TinfE)[1]*
           data(n, hw, he, TinfW, TinfE)[3])

        b[-1] = (gamsor(k,q, TDMA(data, coeff))[1][i]*(grid(x1,x2,data)/2)+ 
            data(n, hw, he, TinfW, TinfE)[2]*
            data(n, hw, he, TinfW, TinfE)[4])

# Change values in first and last coefficients to reflect specified BC's
        Aw[0] = 0
        Ap[0] = Ae[0] + Aw[0] + data(n, hw, he, TinfW, TinfE)[1]

        Ae[-1] = 0
        Ap[-1] = Ae[0] + Aw[0] + data(n, hw, he, TinfW, TinfE)[2]

    return Ae, Aw, Ap, b

 #Step 5: SOLVE
def TDMA(data, coeff):
# Initialize "T" array - the solution array
    T = np.zeros(data(n, hw, he, TinfW, TinfE)[0]);

# Initialize recursion functions as arrays
    P = np.zeros(data(n, hw, he, TinfW, TinfE)[0]);
    Q = np.zeros(data(n, hw, he, TinfW, TinfE)[0]);

## Step 1: evaluate at node 1
    P[0] = (coeff(Ae, Aw, Ap, data, gamsor, grid)[0][0] / 
       coeff(Ae, Aw, Ap, data, gamsor, grid)[2][0])

    Q[0] = (coeff(Ae, Aw, Ap, data, gamsor, grid)[3][0] / 
       coeff(Ae, Aw, Ap, data, gamsor, grid)[2][0])

## Step 2: sweep from node 2 to node (n-1) (python
## cell 1->(n-2) ) evaluating P and Q

    for i in range(1, data(n, hw, he, TinfW, TinfE)[0]-1):
        P[i] = ((coeff(Ae, Aw, Ap, data, gamsor, grid)[0][i]) / 
           (coeff(Ae, Aw, Ap, data, gamsor, grid)[2][i] - 
           coeff(Ae, Aw, Ap, data, gamsor, grid)[1][i]*P[i-1]))

        Q[i] = ((coeff(Ae, Aw, Ap, data, gamsor, grid)[3][i] + 
           coeff(Ae, Aw, Ap, data, gamsor, grid)[1][i]*Q[i-1]) / 
           (coeff(Ae, Aw, Ap, data, gamsor, grid)[2][i] - 
           coeff(Ae, Aw, Ap, data, gamsor, grid)[1][i]*P[i-1]))

## Step 3: calculate for node n

    P[data(n, hw, he, TinfW, TinfE)[0]-1] = 0

    Q[data(n, hw, he, TinfW, TinfE)[0]-1] = ( 
(coeff(Ae, Aw, Ap, data, gamsor, grid)[3][data(n, hw, he, 
TinfW, TinfE)[0]-1] + coeff(Ae, Aw, Ap, data, gamsor, grid)
[1][data(n, hw, he, TinfW, TinfE)[0]-1]*Q[data(n, hw, he, TinfW, 
TinfE)[0]-2]) / (coeff(Ae, Aw, Ap, data, gamsor, grid)[2][data(n, 
hw, he, TinfW, TinfE)[0]-1] - coeff(Ae, Aw, Ap, data, gamsor, 
grid)[1][data(n, hw, he, TinfW, TinfE)[0]-1]*P[data(n, hw, he, 
TinfW, TinfE)[0]-2]))

    T[data(n, hw, he, TinfW, TinfE)[0]-1] = ( 
    Q[data(n, hw, he, TinfW, TinfE)[0]-1] )

## Step 4: back fill, giving the temperatures
    for i in range(data(n, hw, he, TinfW, TinfE)[0] - 2, -1, -1):
        T[i] = P[i]*T[i+1] + Q[i]

    return T

def Temps(TDMA):
    Temps = copy.copy(TDMA(data,coeff)); Temps.fill(100)
    return Temps

if __name__ == '__main__': 

# Initialize variables
    n = 0
    hw = 0
    he = 0
    TinfW = 0
    TinfE = 0

    k = np.zeros(data(n, hw, he, TinfW, TinfE)[0])
    q = np.zeros(data(n, hw, he, TinfW, TinfE)[0])
    k0 = 0
    beta = 20
    T0 = 0

    x1 = 0
    x2 = 0

    Ae = np.zeros(data(n, hw, he, TinfW, TinfE)[0])
    Aw = np.zeros(data(n, hw, he, TinfW, TinfE)[0])
    Ap = np.zeros(data(n, hw, he, TinfW, TinfE)[0])
    b = 0

    data(n, hw, he, TinfW, TinfE)
    grid(x1, x2, data)

    Temps(TDMA)
    for _ in range(1):
        gamsor(k, q)
        coeff(Ae, Aw, Ap, data, gamsor, grid)
        TDMA(data, coeff)

#print Temps(TDMA) 



    print "Nodal Temperature Distribution (C):", TDMA(data, coeff)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I got problem right, the possible solution is using something like

```
from itertools import cycle
caller = cycle((func1, func2, func3))
```

And then you should run

```
caller.next()(<arguments>)
```

and store results somewhere to check for convergency.

Comment: Thanks for the fast help. I think cycle is what I was looking for. I used cycle like you recommended and didn't get any errors. Once I try to get the next/last output values from the TDMA function, I still keep getting the maximum recursion depth error for some reason.